# What does += mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've been looking online for this answer, and it's so simple so I'm embaressed for asking, but what exactly does the "+=" do in javascript.  I don't know why but I can't seem to find this on google. Please help.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is syntactic sugar that allows you to add something to a variable and store the result in that variable, that is

```
x += 2;
```

is equivalent to

```
x = x + 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose

```
var i = 5;
```

You can add 6 to `i` by writing

```
i = i + 6;
```

Or the equivalent short-hand way:

```
i += 6;
```

Answer (score 1):

`a += b;` is a short form of `a = a + b;`